# How can I add random audio on canvas everytime I hit an object?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, audio

I'm new to programming. I tried to do a snake game using canvas. I want to add an random audio everytime I hit an obstacle. When I add one audio, it works completely fine but I can't do the same thing with two audios. I tried to do using an array etc. but it didn't work. How can I work this?

JAVASCRIPT

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('oyun');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let speed = 7;

let tileCount = 24;
let tileSize = canvas.width / tileCount - 2;
let headX = 12;
let headY = 12;

let appleX = 5;
let appleY = 5;

let audio = document.getElementById("sesefekt");

let xVelocity = 0;
let yVelocity = 0;

 function drawGame(){
     changeSnakePosition();
     checkAppleCollision();
     clearScreen();
     drawApple();
     drawSnake(); 
     setTimeout(drawGame, 1000 / speed);
 }

 function clearScreen(){
     ctx.fillStyle = '#a40af7';
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 }

 function drawSnake() {
     ctx.fillStyle = 'purple';
     ctx.fillRect(headX * tileCount, headY * tileCount, tileSize,tileSize);
 }

 function changeSnakePosition() {
     headX = headX + xVelocity;
     headY = headY + yVelocity;
 }

 function drawApple() {
     ctx.fillStyle = "plum";
     ctx.fillRect(appleX * tileCount, appleY * tileCount, tileSize, tileSize);
 }

function checkAppleCollision() {
    if(appleX == headX && appleY == headY){
        appleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * tileCount);
        appleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * tileCount);
        audio.play();  
    }
}

//hareket etme fonksiyonları
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);

function keyDown(event) {
    //yukarı
    if (event.keyCode == 38){
        if(yVelocity == 1)
            return;
        yVelocity = -1;
        xVelocity = 0;
    }
    //aşağı
    if (event.keyCode == 40){
        if(yVelocity == -1)
            return;
        yVelocity = 1;
        xVelocity = 0;
    }
    //sağ
    if (event.keyCode == 39){
        if(xVelocity == -1)
            return;
        yVelocity = 0;
        xVelocity = 1;
    }
    //sol
    if (event.keyCode == 37){
        if(xVelocity == +1)
            return;
        yVelocity = 0;
        xVelocity = -1;
    }
}

 drawGame();
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SNAKE YILANNNNNN</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: black;   
        }
        canvas{
            box-shadow: darkmagenta 20px 10px 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <audio id="sesefekt">
        <source src="bruh.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <source src="a.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>

    <h1 style="color: blueviolet; text-shadow: lightblue 20px 10px 50px;">YILAN OYUNU AMA BİR DEĞİŞİK</h1>

    <canvas id="oyun" width="576" height="576"></canvas>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are essentially hitting play every time there is a collision. If the sound effect is already playing you cant start it again. There a few ways of solving this that I can think of:

1. create a new element whenever you need to play a sound effect and remove it as soon as the effect finishes
2. use an API/framework like this one [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) [examples](https://github.com/mdn/webaudio-examples/)

Comment: thanks I'm going to try that